# Getting a redirect loop when using Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

In my Laravel application I use the `auth` Middleware to ensure only authenticated users can reach particular routes.

So, in my `routes/web.php` I have something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'user.required.fields']], function () {

}
```

As you can see I've added an extra Middleware: `user.required.fields` it looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckUserRequiredFields
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->has_filled_required_fields){
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->route('new-user');
        }
    }
}
```

The attribute in question looks like this:

```
/**
 * If the user has filled in their role, department and location, allow full access to the intranet
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function getHasFilledRequiredFieldsAttribute()
{
    if ($this->role && $this->department && $this->location) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, this causes an infinite loop.

Is there something in the `auth` middleware that would cause this? It's almost like the middleware calls itself over and over.

The code will correctly redirect to `route('new-user`)` but then repeatedly hits the route.

Comment: Is route `new-user` defined within that group? If so, that might be your problem. Also, could you do some basic debugging and tell us _if_ and _where_ the code is making it to in your middleware?

Comment: Yes it's defined within the group

Comment: So, is it essentially redirecting to itself?

Comment: It hits returning the route, but then returns the same route over and over

Comment: What does the `new-user` page do? Do you need to be an authenticated user to access it?

Comment: Yes, it allows you to fill in option parts of the user table

Comment: OK - then you might have to rethink your routes a bit because `new-user` fails the `has_filled_required_fields` check and then redirects to `new-user`, which fails the `has_filled_required_fields` check, which redirects to `new-user`, which ....

Comment: You could attach that middleware to specific routes OR create a sub-group and attach it there which would _exclude_ `new-user`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your `route('new-user')` defined within this group:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'user.required.fields']], function () {
    //
}
```

So, it will be checked by the middleware, that returns the same route again and again, which cause the mentioned loop.

A possible solution is to remove the route from this grop and also not protect it with the `CheckUserRequiredFields` middleware.